# Newtonsoft JSON.NET parse to array of custom key/value pair objects

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have this strange issue with parsing given JSON data. I have this JSON structure:

```
{"value":[
  {"street":"Karlova 25"},
  {"city":"Prague"},
  {"gpsLat":"50.1571"},
  {"gpsLon":"15.0482"}
]}
```

How to parse this structure using Newtonsoft JSON.NET library? I tried to use my own JsonConverter class:

```
public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer){
  JArray jarray = (JArray)((JTokenReader)reader).CurrentToken;
  List<AddressValue> values = new List<AddressValue>();
  foreach (var jobj in jarray.Children<JObject>()){
    foreach (JProperty prop in jobj.Properties()){
      values.Add(new AddressValue() { Label = prop.Name, Value = prop.Value.ToString() });
    }
  }
  return values.ToArray();
}

class AddressValue{
  public string Label { get; set; }
  public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

but I have got an exception:

```
Exception thrown: 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' in Newtonsoft.Json.DLL

Additional information: Unexpected token when deserializing object: StartObject. Path 'value[0]'.
```

EDIT:
I also tried to save this to Dictionary:

```
 [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "value")]
 public Dictionary<string, string> Value{get; set;}
```

But I have another exception:

```
$exception  {"Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String]' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"}) to deserialize correctly.\r\nTo fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List<T> that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.\r\nPath 'param.value'."}
```

What I am doing wrong? Thank you for your answers.

Comment: In visual studio, you can Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste JSON as Classes, then DeserializeObject<ClassName>(stringData).

Comment: That is not an array, it is a Dictionary at worst, but you should be able to declare an Address class with properties that are the same as the JSON keys, and deserialize directly. @crashmstr 's comment may work in newer versions of VS, but creating the destination class is also an option.

Comment: I forgot to add that in question but saving data in dictionary also dont work. I will edit my question :-)

Comment: What does your `AddressValue` class look like?

Comment: @dbc I have edited the question.

Comment: I just answered for `Dictionary<string, string> Value` - is that enough?

Comment: @dbc Thank you again. It works perfectly. I also accepted you answer :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you want to represent a `Dictionary<string, string>` in your JSON as an array of objects, where each nested object has one key and value from the dictionary.  You can do it with the following converter:

```
public class DictionaryToDictionaryListConverter<TKey, TValue> : JsonConverter 
{
    class DictionaryDTO : Dictionary<TKey, TValue>
    {
        public DictionaryDTO(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> pair) : base(1) { Add(pair.Key, pair.Value); }
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(IDictionary<TKey, TValue>).IsAssignableFrom(objectType) && objectType != typeof(DictionaryDTO);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;
        var token = JToken.Load(reader);
        var dict = (IDictionary<TKey, TValue>)(existingValue as IDictionary<TKey, TValue> ?? serializer.ContractResolver.ResolveContract(objectType).DefaultCreator());
        if (token.Type == JTokenType.Array)
        {
            foreach (var item in token)
                using (var subReader = item.CreateReader())
                    serializer.Populate(subReader, dict);
        }
        else if (token.Type == JTokenType.Object)
        {
            using (var subReader = token.CreateReader())
                serializer.Populate(subReader, dict);

        }
        return dict;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var dict = (IDictionary<TKey, TValue>)value;
        // Prevent infinite recursion of converters by using DictionaryDTO
        serializer.Serialize(writer, dict.Select(p => new DictionaryDTO(p)));
    }
}
```

Then use it in your container class as follows:

```
public class RootObject
{
    [JsonProperty("value")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(DictionaryToDictionaryListConverter<string, string>))]
    public Dictionary<string, string> Value { get; set; }
}
```

Note that the converter will throw an exception during reading if the keys are not unique.

**Update**

For `AddressValue` you could use the following converter:

```
public class AddressValueConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(AddressValue);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;
        var addressValue = (existingValue as AddressValue ?? new AddressValue());
        var token = JObject.Load(reader);
        var property = token.Properties().SingleOrDefault();
        if (property != null)
        {
            addressValue.Label = property.Name;
            addressValue.Value = (string)property.Value;
        }
        return addressValue;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var addressValue = (AddressValue)value;
        serializer.Serialize(writer, new Dictionary<string, string> { { addressValue.Label, addressValue.Value } });
    }
}
```

Then use it as follows:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(AddressValueConverter))]
public class AddressValue
{
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    [JsonProperty("value")]
    public List<AddressValue> Value { get; set; }
}
```

Demo fiddle with both options [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RdT3mX).

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to reinvent the wheel. This funcionality is already working.
Create classes like below:

```
public class Value
{
    public string street { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
    public string gpsLat { get; set; }
    public string gpsLon { get; set; }
}

public class MyClass
{
    public List<Value> value { get; set; }
}
```

Now You can simply deserialize your json to your poco object.

```
MyClass result  = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(youJson);
```

Comment: Thanks but this is not what I need. I am given this JSON from web service and in future JSON may be changed. I need to have both sides (key and value) added dynamicaly as they come from the server.