# JSON array to C# Dictionary

Tags: c#, json, json.net

How do I convert a JSON **array** like this

```
[{"myKey":"myValue"},
{"anotherKey":"anotherValue"}]
```

to a C# Dictionary with json.net or system classes.

json.net can serialize directly to a dictionary, **but only if you feed it an object**, not an array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I deserialize JSON to a simple Dictionary<string,string> in ASP.NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207731/how-can-i-deserialize-json-to-a-simple-dictionarystring-string-in-asp-net)

Comment: Not a duplicate. My JSON is an array. That's a constraint.

Comment: But it does look like a duplicate of [Newtonsoft JSON.NET parse to array of custom key/value pair objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33552322/3744182), agree?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe converting to array of KeyValuePairs will help

```
using System.Linq;

var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>>(jsonContent);
var dictionary = list.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

Comment: Did this actually work for you? I got the correct number of kvps but they had null keys and values. I think it is because Json.Net can't construct them with the Create() method. I ended up having to use a list of single element dictionaries.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work.  An `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>` will serialize as `[{"Key":"myKey","Value":"myValue"},{"Key":"anotherKey","Value":"anotherValue"}]` not `[{"myKey":"myValue"},{"anotherKey":"anotherValue"}]`.  See: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ChfYuV.

Comment: Its incorrect and not working.

Answer (score 6):

For anyone interested - this works, too:

Example JSON:

> [{"device_id":"VC2","command":6,"command_args":"test args10"},
>   {"device_id":"VC2","command":3,"command_args":"test args9"}]

C#:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<JObject>>(json)
            .Select(x => x?.ToObject<Dictionary<string, string>>())
            .ToList()
```

Answer (score 5):

Its quite simple actually :

lets say you get your json in a string like :

```
string jsonString = @"[{"myKey":"myValue"},
{"anotherKey":"anotherValue"}]";
```

then you can deserialize it using JSON.NET as follows:

```
JArray a = JArray.Parse(jsonString);

// dictionary hold the key-value pairs now
Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

foreach (JObject o in a.Children<JObject>())
{
    foreach (JProperty p in o.Properties())
    {
        string name = p.Name;
        string value = (string)p.Value;
        dict.Add(name,value);
    }
}
```

Comment: @user1585345 what do you mean?

Comment: my apologies for not reading it right - i have updated the code!

Answer (score 3):

I found that using a list of KeyValuePairs didn't work. I got the right number of elements but they had null Keys and Values.

In the end the only solution that worked for me was deserialising to a list of dictionaries (which each had a single kvp element).

Answer (score 0):

The data must to be sent as follows (format):

```
"Values": [
  {"Key" : "abc"  , "Value": 23.14},
  {"Key" : "abc1" , "Value": 23.11},
  {"Key" : "abc2" , "Value": 23.17},
  {"Key" : "abc3" , "Value": 23.19}
]
```

thereby, the converting process will work. It worked fine to me in my attempt to convert from JSON to `dictionary<string,decimal>`

Answer (score 0):

Since you can only deserialize from an object, do just that by manipulating the JSON string a little first. Wrap it in an object:

```
json = String.Format("{{\"result\":{0}}}", json);
```