# Cannot deserialize Json file to a list of KeyValuePair with string "key"

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have hard time deserializing the json response from Solr search engine.

I use Newtonsoft Json.NET.

Simplified response from Solr:

```json
{
   "suggestions": [
      {
         "someword": {
            "numFound": 1
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

I deserialize this to a list of `KeyValuePair<string, customobject>`.

```csharp
customobject test = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<customobject>(jsonText);
```

It worked, until a user typed the word "key", so Solr returned that JSON:

```json
{
   "suggestions": [
      {
         "key": {
            "numFound": 1
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

The deserialization of this JSON raise this error :

> Unexpected character encountered while parsing value

...
Ok. I just realized that even if it doesn't raise an exception with words other than "key", it doesn't work because the KeyValuePair in the output object are always empty.

I had never realized this problem before because this part of the Json (Spellcheck Suggestions) is never used.

So easy fix: we do not serialize suggestions anymore.

But, if anyone still want to answer the question, in what kind of object will you deserialize this Json (from Solr)?

```json
{
    "suggestions":
    [
      {"brack":{
        "numFound":10,
        "startOffset":0,
        "endOffset":5,
        "origFreq":0,
        "suggestion":[{
            "word":"back",
            "freq":78},
          {
            "word":"black",
            "freq":1}
          ]}},
      {"key":{
        "numFound":1,
        "startOffset":6,
        "endOffset":9,
        "origFreq":12,
        "suggestion":[{
            "word":"key",
            "freq":15}]}}]
}
```

I don't think a dictionary can do the job :

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,Test.SpellCheckSuggestion]' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.

Comment: What if you try to deserialize it to a Dictionary<string, customobject>? Dictionary should be a collection of key/value pairs with unique keys

Comment: Please include the code for CustomObject and the code you're using to deserialize.

Comment: @Dan can you post a more complete example, including your `CustomObject`?

Comment: *I deserialize this to a list of `KeyValuePair<string, customobject>`* - then please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem by including your data model.  See [ask].  `public List<Dictionary<string, Result>> Suggestions { get; set; }` works fine for all JSON shown in your question, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/e8uEiC so I can't reproduce your issue.

Comment: *I don't think a dictionnary can do the job* - did you try `List<Dictionary<string, SpellCheckSuggestion>>` as was suggested above?

Comment: @dbc, you're right, it works with a list of dictionary. Is it a good practice to use this kind of structure?

Comment: @Dan - well that's the structure of the JSON so that's how you will need to deserialize it.  If you find that structure to be inconvenient you could later map it to something else such as a `Dictionary<string, SpellCheckSuggestion>` (if you are sure the keys are unique) or a `Dictionary<string, SpellCheckSuggestion>>` if you are not.  What is your final, preferred data model?

Comment: For instance if you would prefer `Dictionary<string, SpellCheckSuggestion>` you could use `DictionaryToDictionaryListConverter<string, SpellCheckSuggestion>` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33553237/3744182) to [Newtonsoft JSON.NET parse to array of custom key/value pair objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33552322/3744182).

Comment: @dbc - Thanks for your help! I marked this question as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment above, the solution is to use a list of dictionary. (not just a dictionary and not a list of KeyValuePair)

```csharp
List<Dictionary<string, SpellCheckSuggestion>>
```